# Converting date to specified format and two date comparisions

Tags: perl

Given Two Dates:

**$Date1**

```
format: yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss eg:  2013-05-21 07:47:21
```

**$Date2**

```
format: Day Month date hh:mm:ss yyyy eg: Thu Aug  1 09:53:40 2013
```

How to compare $Date1 and $Date2?

I want to do following operation:

if($Date2>=$Date1){
  //Do some operation
}

But I am not able to make comparison as the two dates are in different Format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
use Time::Piece;
my $d1 = '2013-05-21 07:47:21';
my $d2 = 'Thu Aug  1 09:53:40 2013';
my $t1 = Time::Piece->strptime($d1, "%Y-%m-%d %T");
my $t2 = Time::Piece->strptime($d2, "%c");
say $t2->epoch - $t1->epoch;
```

**output:**

```
6228379
```

[Time::Piece documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/Piece.html)

Answer (score 0):

Parse the date using regular expressions and use the [Time::Local](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Time-Local/lib/Time/Local.pm) functions to convert into seconds past 1 Jan 1970 to compare integers.